# how to dismiss a subview by a button inside the same subview which is a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift2

I am having 2 UIViewControllers. The first ViewController has a label,view and a button the second view has a label,text box and add button and at the bottom ok button.Both ViewControllers have separate swift files. when i press the button in the 1st ViewController it presents the second view controller as a sub view. In the sub view all works fine

But when i press the ok button i want the sub view to be dismissed.I searched on google but i could not find any relative answer.

Note: I am using Xcode 7.1.1 swift2. The Cancel button must be placed in the subView.

the code used to show the second view as sub view

```
    let object = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("caller") as? ViewController
    self.view.addSubview(object!.view)
```

here caller - 2nd viewController StoryBoard ID .
ViewController - 2nd ViewController

Comment: can you show some code of how you present the 2nd viewcontroller?

Comment: @AndréSlotta See Edited

Answer (score 0):

i think instead of adding the second viewcontroller's view as a subview of your first viewcontroller what you really should (and maybe even wanna) do is the following:

in your first viewcontroller to present the second viewcontroller:

```
let vc2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("caller")
presentViewController(vc2!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

in your second viewcontroller to dismiss the first viewcontroller:

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This works really good.But the second view hides the first view.Instead i want it like an alert view where the old screen is still present but only the popup is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options
1. In the second view controller in the button action method add this line `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`

**cons:** usually the view controller is not the one responsible for his dismissal

**pros:** easy

2. If you are using Swift you can try to add a completion handler:
   in the second ViewController add this
   `var completionHandler: (() -> Void)? = nil`
   in the action you call it like this `self.completionHandler?()`

in the first view after the initialisation of the second view you, can you use this to take action

```
secondViewController.completionHandler = {
secondViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

**pros:** i like closures

**cons:** did not found yet

3. You can use delegate methods
   **pros:** delegates
   **cons:** i like closure more

FYI As you didn't tell us how you present your view my solution is done assuming that u use `presentViewController` for presenting

**UPDATE**

I saw that you updated your question, in this case method nr 2. is the one to go only change to this

```
object.completionHandler = {
    object.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

The only thing i would like to add you dont add a ViewController as a subview, you use a UIView for that

Comment: thanks for the answer.But the way you do actually hides the whole view controller.Instead i want the second ViewController to show like a popup or alert view.

Comment: In this case as i mantion you dont need to use a ViewController, create a custom View

Answer (score 0):

**For** showing the present view controller

`let presentVC = FirstViewController();
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(presentVC, animated: true, completion: nil)`

And on "SecondViewController" button click action

`self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`

I think this will work.

Comment: thanks for the answer.But This method hides the whole screen.Instead i want the second ViewController to show like a popup or alert view.

Comment: Do you want that on the button ( in SecondViewController) click the SecondViewController should stay in front of 1st view controller as an alert view ?